# NGINX: Please explain proxy_ssl_verify_depth in detail

Tags: nginx, ssl

Can someone please explain how exactly `proxy_ssl_verify_depth` property works in the ngx_http_proxy_module?

The definition is rather short - *Sets the verification depth in the proxied HTTPS server certificates chain.*

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this property has been explained in an [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/206409/70406) from Z.T. in Security Stack Exchange :

> I think this is DoS prevention: building the chain might be an exponential algorithm with backoff, so with the [openssl default of 100](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/crypto/x509/x509_vpm.c#L482) a malicious backend might cause denial of service in nginx. I would use 10. In practice, 4 should be enough.